# Remove "Tech. Rep." Output from SIAM bibtex style

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I've got the following Problem using the SIAM bibtex style. Consider the following bib entry

```
@TECHREPORT{Pap1,
  author = {Author One},
  title = {Paper Title},
  institution = {My Institute},
  year = {2011},
  number = {XXX/YY-ZZ},
  month = {December},
}
```

and

```
\nocite{Pap1}
\bibliographystyle{siam} 
\bibliography{bibfile}
```

to generate the bibliography. Then the output is

```
 A. ONE, Paper title, Tech. Rep. XXX/YY-ZZ, My Institute, December 2011.
```

How can I remove the "Tech. Rep." from the output? Setting type={} in the bibtex entry does not help and type={~} removes the "Tech. Rep. but inserts an unwanted whitespace before the number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this particular case

```
type={\unskip\space},
```

seems to work.

Comment: If i enter \unskip\space in the type-filed of Jabref, it does not remove the comma and the bibliography entry compiles like: ........University, , 21. September 2012. How can this be fixed, if using \bibliographystyle{unsrtdin}
\bibliography{MyBibtexFile.bib}

Comment: @Fry This is specific for `siam.bst`; `unsrtdin` is a different beast.