# Remove (Tech.Rep.) from Bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, apa6

I have a case similar to this one :

[Remove "Tech. Rep." Output from SIAM bibtex style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45956/remove-tech-rep-output-from-siam-bibtex-style)

but using apacite. When I did what was advised in the above-mentioned topic, the result was the () but without the words in them, i.e from ".....(Tech.Rep.)..." to "...()...". Is there a way to get rid of the brackets and to apply this globally for the entire bibliography rather than entry by entry?

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{apacite}

\begin{document}
\cite{iso3}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{alternative}
\end{document}


@techreport{iso3,
Author = {ISO/IEC },
Date-Added = {2013-04-10 19:39:43 +0000},
Date-Modified = {2013-04-14 05:05:06 +0000},
Institution = { International Organization for Standardization, Geneva, Switzerland.},
Title = {{ISO}/{IEC} 9126-1:2001, {S}oftware engineering - {P}roduct quality, {P}art 1:{Q}uality model},
Year = {2001}}
```

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: Added MWE to the original post.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following redefinition:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{apacite}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\APACbVolEdTR}[2]{%
  \ifx\@empty#1\@empty
    \ifx\@empty#2\@empty
    \else%
      \unskip\hbox{}%            (Technical Report No.\ <no>)
    \fi%
  \else%
    ({#1}%               (2nd ed., Vol.~1
    \ifx\@empty#2\@empty%
    \else%
      \unskip; {#2}%     ; Technical Report No.\ <no>
    \fi%
    )%                   Final parenthesis.
  \fi%
}
\makeatother
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{alternative.bib}
@techreport{iso3,
Author = {ISO/IEC },
Date-Added = {2013-04-10 19:39:43 +0000},
Date-Modified = {2013-04-14 05:05:06 +0000},
Institution = { International Organization for Standardization, Geneva, Switzerland.},
Title = {{ISO}/{IEC} 9126-1:2001, {S}oftware engineering - {P}roduct quality, {P}art 1:{Q}uality model},
Year = {2001}}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\cite{iso3}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{alternative}
\end{document}
```

> [image]