# Latex referencing report without [tech.rep] in reference list

Tags: biblatex

I have a similar question as: [Remove "Tech. Rep." Output from SIAM bibtex style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45956/remove-tech-rep-output-from-siam-bibtex-style)

In my document I reference different reports in APA style. However, in my reference list they include [tech.rep] which is not something that is normally used in APA style.
How can I delete this?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber, maxcitenames=2, style=apa, sorting=anyt]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\usepackage[autostyle, english = british]{csquotes}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\parencite{b20_taskforce_open_2017}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

and the following bib entry:

```
@techreport{b20_taskforce_open_2017,
title = {Open, dynamic and inclusive labor markets: {Harnessing} the potential of technological change and creating a global level playing field},
url = {https://www.uscib.org/uscib-content/uploads/2017/05/B20-Policy-Paper-EE_final.pdf},
urldate = {2020-06-07},
author = {{B20 Taskforce}},
year = {2017},
file = {B20-Policy-Paper-EE_final.pdf:C\:\\Users\\eszti\\Zotero\\storage\\XDQIBP4B\\B20-Policy-Paper-EE_final.pdf:application/pdf}
}
```

Which gives the following output in the reference list:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Completely unrelated to your question, but with a current version of `biblatex-apa`, `maxcitenames=2,` is already the default and with an older version of `biblatex-apa` or with `biblatex-apa6` `maxcitenames=2` famously didn't work as expected (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/452032/35864). I also wouldn't set `sorting=anyt,`. `biblatex-apa` comes with its own (APA compliant) sorting scheme and in any case `anyt` makes little sense with an author-year style since it would sort after the alphabetic labels that styles like `alphabetic` produce.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. How do I change that in my file?

Comment: Just don't use `maxcitenames=2,` and `sorting=anyt`, i.e. shorten `\usepackage[backend=biber, maxcitenames=2, style=apa, sorting=anyt]{biblatex}` to `\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa,]{biblatex}`. (Generally, I'd say unless you know exactly what and option does and why you need it, chances are you don't actually want it and it should be dropped).

Comment: Thank you, it works :) I deleted those lines and the format did not change so this is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to get rid of the "tech. rep." is to make your entry of type `@report` instead of `@techreport`.

In `biblatex` `@techreport` is only a (BibTeX) compatibility alias that is resolved to a `@report` entry with added `type = {techreport}` (only if `type` is not already set).

If you use `@report` directly, you are free not to include the `type = {techreport},` that `@techreport` would add automatically.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle, english = british]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@report{b20_taskforce_open_2017,
  title   = {Open, Dynamic and Inclusive Labor Markets:
             {Harnessing} the Potential of Technological Change
             and Creating a Global Level Playing Field},
  url     = {https://www.uscib.org/uscib-content/uploads/2017/05/B20-Policy-Paper-EE_final.pdf},
  urldate = {2020-06-07},
  author  = {{B20 Taskforce}},
  year    = {2017},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{b20_taskforce_open_2017}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: B20 Taskforce. (2017). Open, dynamic and inclusive labor markets: Harnessing the potential of technological change and creating a global level playing field. Retrieved June 7, 2020, from https://www.uscib.org/uscib-content/uploads/2017/05/B20-Policy-Paper-EE_final.pdf]

---

In case you must stick with `@techreport` you can use the following `\DeclareSourcemap` to get in with a mapping from `@techreport` to `@report` before `biblatex`'s standard type mapping kicks in. That way can we avoid `type = {techreport},` being added to the entry.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle, english = british]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}


\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[typesource=techreport, typetarget=report]
    }
  }
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@techreport{b20_taskforce_open_2017,
  title   = {Open, Dynamic and Inclusive Labor Markets:
             {Harnessing} the Potential of Technological Change
             and Creating a Global Level Playing Field},
  url     = {https://www.uscib.org/uscib-content/uploads/2017/05/B20-Policy-Paper-EE_final.pdf},
  urldate = {2020-06-07},
  author  = {{B20 Taskforce}},
  year    = {2017},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{b20_taskforce_open_2017}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is really easy, thank you! I use zotero to get my reference in bibtex. He must change it automatically to tech report, dont know why though.

Comment: @es_dutch See the update, please. It is probably possible to tell Zotero to export to `@report` with the [BetterBibTeX plugin](https://retorque.re/zotero-better-bibtex/), but I wouldn't know how.

Comment: Thank you, but that is okay, there are only a few cases so I can change them manually for now.

Comment: When exporting as "Better BibLaTeX", BBT exports as `@techreport` if the `type` field says exactly `techreport`, otherwise it exports as `@report`. With `Better BibTeX` export it is always `@techreport`, but I can change that if desired (please open an issue on GH) or you can add `tex.referencetype: report` to the `extra` field.

Comment: @es_dutch See the comment of the BetterBibTeX developer above.